# adding no-smoothState to link still tries to load with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, smoothstate.js

I am using the jQuery SmoothState.js plugin and I have one link that I dont want it to load.

I have added the class `no-smoothState` as suggested in the documentation but it still loads the page with ajax rather than redirect.

```
<a href="/login" class="btn btn-prim no-smoothState">Sign-in</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Really late here but if anyone else comes across this issue. The .noSmoothstate needs to be the first class on the anchor/element. At least this was my case.

```
<a class="no-smoothState button" href="#">My Link</a>
```